# filenotfound exception while storing image to mysql database in netbeans java web app project

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, netbeans-7

```
  File filePath = new File("/images/img1g.png");
     System.out.println("Attempting to read from file in: "+filePath.getCanonicalPath());FileInputStream ins=new FileInputStream(filePath);
```

StackTrace:Attempting to read from file in: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.14\bin\images\img1g.png

while imgage location is: "MyProject/web/images"

Comment: You are using absolute file path. Did you try removing the prefix `/`? we need to know where does this actual class file exist?

Comment: Its trying to read the file from C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.14\bin\images\img1g.png